Threejs Phone vertical sticky carousel react-three/fiber

I have stacked the sticky areas - but how to add the text in the same style/manner. Also I've created refs for each of the phone scenes - but its no longer sticking - and I am unsure what causes it to stick in the first place to control how long the user sees each part?
This renders multiple phones - but the sticky aspect has got lost
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-3zpm73
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'
import * as THREE from 'three'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const IphoneModel = (ref) => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    video.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2024/07/14/221180_tiny.mp4'
    video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    video.loop = true
    video.muted = true
    video.play()

    const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding

    materials.Screen.map = videoTexture
    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ref[0],
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: -Math.PI / 8, duration: 2 })
  }, [materials.Screen])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI / 8]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}

const Background = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree()
  useEffect(() => {
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('#555555')
  }, [scene])

  return null
}

const TextSection = () => {
  const textRefs = useRef([])

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.fromTo(
      textRefs.current,
      { opacity: 0 },
      {
        opacity: 1,
        stagger: 0.1,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '#text-trigger',
          start: 'top bottom',
          end: 'center center',
          scrub: 1,
          markers: false
        }
      }
    )
  }, [])

  const texts = ['Ready 5', 'Ready 4', 'Ready 3', 'Ready 2', 'Ready 1']

  return (
    <div
      id="text-trigger"
      style={{
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
        top: '500px'
      }}>
      {texts.map((text, index) => (
        <h1 key={index} ref={(el) => (textRefs.current[index] = el)} style={{ opacity: 0 }}>
          {text}
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const ThreeScene = () => {
  const threeSceneGroup = useRef()

  return (
    <div id="three-canvas-container" style={{ width: '100vw', height: '500px' }}>
      <div>
        <h2>header text</h2>
        <p>text text text</p>
      </div>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 45 }} gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: false }}>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
        <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7.5]} intensity={1} />
        <IphoneModel ref={threeSceneGroup} />
        <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
        <Background />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '400vh' }}>
    <div className="some-content" style={{ height: '100vh', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <h1>ACTION</h1>
    </div>
    <ThreeScene />
    <ThreeScene />
    <ThreeScene />
    <ThreeScene />
    <ThreeScene />

    <TextSection />
  </div>
)

export default App

This renders just one phone but actually has working sticky features.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-jns24q
app.js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'
import * as THREE from 'three'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const IphoneModel = () => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    video.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2024/07/14/221180_tiny.mp4'
    video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    video.loop = true
    video.muted = true
    video.play()

    const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    videoTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding

    materials.Screen.map = videoTexture
    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '#three-canvas-container',
        scrub: 1,
        markers: true,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top'
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI * 2, duration: 2 })
  }, [materials.Screen])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, -Math.PI / 8]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}

const Background = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree()
  useEffect(() => {
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('#555555')
  }, [scene])

  return null
}

const TextSection = () => {
  const textRefs = useRef([])

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.fromTo(
      textRefs.current,
      { opacity: 0 },
      {
        opacity: 1,
        stagger: 0.1,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: '#text-trigger',
          start: 'top bottom',
          end: 'center center',
          scrub: 1,
          markers: false
        }
      }
    )
  }, [])

  const texts = ['Ready 5', 'Ready 4', 'Ready 3', 'Ready 2', 'Ready 1']

  return (
    <div
      id="text-trigger"
      style={{
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
        top: '500px'
      }}>
      {texts.map((text, index) => (
        <h1 key={index} ref={(el) => (textRefs.current[index] = el)} style={{ opacity: 0 }}>
          {text}
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const ThreeScene = () => (
  <div id="three-canvas-container" style={{ width: '100vw', height: '500px' }}>
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 45 }} gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: false }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
      <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7.5]} intensity={1} />
      <IphoneModel />
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
      <Background />
    </Canvas>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '400vh' }}>
    <div className="some-content" style={{ height: '100vh', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <h1>ACTION</h1>
    </div>
    <ThreeScene />
    <TextSection />
  </div>
)

export default App


I was having issues trying to get the image the right way up -- and found this vector2 function did the trick
const imageTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image)
    
imageTexture.wrapS = imageTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
imageTexture.anisotropy = 16

imageTexture.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(1, -1)

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-xwt2x6

Sandbox not found - your sandboxes don't open... Check bookmark public/private access

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-jns24q -- should be public - renders one phone with working sticky

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-3zpm73 - should be public - renders multiple phones - but the sticky is broken? not sure how or what controls it to be sticky in the first place

any luck? I am not sure why the sticky is broken or how to ensure these are rendered as separate components - I am not sure if the video src update will work in this manner - as it may make all of them have the same video?

Try something like this, probably in next question you will ask how make animation of showing/hiding of text according to each section... Simply connect opacity: 0=>1=>0 on particular moment of viewport by ScrollTrigger.
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const IphoneModel = ({ modelIndex }) => {
  const group = useRef();
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb');

  useEffect(() => {
    const imageTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/textures/lava/lavatile.jpg'
    );
    materials.Screen.map = imageTexture;
    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true;

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: `#section-${modelIndex}`,
        scrub: 1,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top',
        markers: true
      }
    });

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI * 2, duration: 2 });
  }, [materials.Screen, modelIndex]);

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  );
};

const Background = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree();
  useEffect(() => {
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('#555555');
  }, [scene]);

  return null;
};

const ThreeScene = ({ modelIndex }) => (
  <div
    id={`three-canvas-container-${modelIndex}`}
    style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, width: '50vw', height: '100vh' }}
  >
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 45 }} gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: false }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
      <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7.5]} intensity={1} />
      <IphoneModel modelIndex={modelIndex} />
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
      <Background />
    </Canvas>
  </div>
);

const Section = ({ title, content, modelIndex }) => (
  <div id={`section-${modelIndex}`} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh', position: 'relative' }}>
    <div style={{ width: '50vw', padding: '0 2rem' }}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
    </div>
    <ThreeScene modelIndex={modelIndex} />
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div style={{ height: '300vh' }}>
    <Section
      modelIndex={1}
      title="First Section"
      content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<br />the printing and typesetting industry."
    />
    <Section
      modelIndex={2}
      title="Second Section"
      content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<br />the printing and typesetting industry."
    />
    <Section
      modelIndex={3}
      title="Third Section"
      content="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<br />the printing and typesetting industry."
    />
  </div>
);

export default App;


I've added this to the codesandbox here -- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-h9yhks  - so what controls the sticky -

I've tried to add json to loop over - and make the image from the json - but it turns upside down and has the same image? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-h9yhks

Have the same problem in this caroseul version - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78951127/threejs-with-gsap-zoom-phone-carousel-react-three-fiber

So what exactly do you try achieve?

well I looped over the json - and gave the element the image - but I am unsure if the replacement image isnt taking because of a reference issue

I got it back the right way -- by adding these - after the imageTexture --   but its still showing only the same image -- imageTexture.wrapS = imageTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
imageTexture.anisotropy = 16
imageTexture.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(1, -1)   https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-xwt2x6

why is the video being loaded in as the same for all instances?

// Clone the material to prevent the shared material issue
const screenMaterial = materials.Screen.clone()
screenMaterial.map = imageTexture
screenMaterial.needsUpdate = true
// Apply the cloned material to the screen mesh
nodes.M_Screen.material = screenMaterial


ok this nearly works but now the 1st item is blank ---- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-4qpp6s

needed to keep materials.Screen.map = imageTexture - uncommented

This is the closest I have got so far -- but I am unsure what is controlling the sticky and also why the last image is only being loaded in all of the phones.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-hsq9xh
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import gsap from 'gsap'
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger'

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const IphoneModel = ({ image, modelIndex }) => {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/Iphone15.glb')

  useEffect(() => {
    //const imageTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    //  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/textures/lava/lavatile.jpg'
    //)

    const imageTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image)

    imageTexture.wrapS = imageTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    imageTexture.anisotropy = 16
    imageTexture.repeat = new THREE.Vector2(1, -1)
    //var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: imageTexture })

    materials.Screen.map = imageTexture
    materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true

    const tl = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: `#section-${modelIndex}`,
        scrub: 4,
        pin: true,
        start: 'top top',
        end: 'bottom top',
        markers: true
      }
    })

    tl.to(group.current.rotation, { z: Math.PI / 8, duration: 6 })
  }, [materials.Screen, modelIndex])

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} scale={0.2} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, -Math.PI / 8]}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Cameras.geometry} material={materials.cam} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Glass.geometry} material={materials['glass.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Rough.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Metal_Shiny.geometry} material={materials.metal_Shiny} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Plastic.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Portal.geometry} material={materials['M_Base.001']} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Screen.geometry} material={materials.Screen} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_Speakers.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.M_USB.geometry} material={materials.metal_rough} />
    </group>
  )
}

const Background = () => {
  const { scene } = useThree()
  useEffect(() => {
    scene.background = new THREE.Color('#555555')
  }, [scene])

  return null
}

const ThreeScene = ({ image, modelIndex }) => (
  <div id={`three-canvas-container-${modelIndex}`} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, width: '50vw', height: '100vh' }}>
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 10], fov: 45 }} gl={{ antialias: true, alpha: false }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
      <directionalLight position={[5, 10, 7.5]} intensity={1} />
      <IphoneModel image={image} modelIndex={modelIndex} />
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
      <Background />
    </Canvas>
  </div>
)

const Section = ({ image, title, content, modelIndex }) => (
  <div id={`section-${modelIndex}`} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh', position: 'relative' }}>
    <div style={{ width: '50vw', padding: '0 2rem' }}>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
    </div>
    <ThreeScene image={image} modelIndex={modelIndex} />
  </div>
)

const json = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: '1',
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<br />the printing and typesetting industry.',
    image: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/09/05/17/31/moutains-9025523_1280.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: '2',
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<br />the printing and typesetting industry.',
    image: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/09/29/14/58/road-8284023_1280.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: '3',
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<br />the printing and typesetting industry.',
    image: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/08/18/14/34/folkstone-8978132_1280.jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: '4',
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of<br />the printing and typesetting industry.',
    image: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2024/05/19/18/22/fruit-8773085_1280.jpg'
  }
]

const App = () => (
  <div style={{ height: '300vh' }}>
    {json.map((item, index) => (
      <Section key={index} image={item.image} modelIndex={item.id} title={item.title} content={item.content} />
    ))}
  </div>
)

export default App

--
apparently its a screen cloning issue -- but the first item is blank
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-4qpp6s
let screenMaterial = materials.Screen.clone()
screenMaterial.map = imageTexture

//materials.Screen.map = imageTexture
materials.Screen = screenMaterial

materials.Screen.needsUpdate = true


apparently the issue is cloning --     // Clone the material to prevent the shared material issue
const screenMaterial = materials.Screen.clone()
screenMaterial.map = imageTexture
screenMaterial.needsUpdate = true
// Apply the cloned material to the screen mesh
nodes.M_Screen.material = screenMaterial


ok this nearly works but now the 1st item is blank ---- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-scroll-rig-sticky-box-forked-4qpp6s

needed to keep materials.Screen.map = imageTexture - uncommented
